# Como acessar e alterar objetos dentro de um arquivo XML pela activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, component

boa noite, estou com dificuldade para alterar os componentes de um arquivo XML, quando eu abro o menu Drawer eu clico no botao "acompanhamento" ele abre o xml fragment_acompanhamento.xml, porém nao consigo acessar os componentes deste XML,

**Segue codigo do meu fragment_acompanhamento**
 `

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonteste"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewteste" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewteste"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

`

**Segue abaixo o codigo da activity criado através do Navigation Drawer Activity**

```
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
public TextView textoemail, textViewNome, textViewTeste;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_visita, R.id.nav_acompanhamento
    )
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_sair:
            deslogarUsuario();
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void deslogarUsuario(){
    try {
        autenticacao.signOut();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

e agora o codigo do **AcompanhamentoFragment.java**

```
private Button btnteste;
private TextView txtteste;

public AcompanhamentoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acompanhamento, container, false);

}
```

oque eu preciso é modificar os componetes da tela *fragment_acompanhamento.xml* como por exemplo um textView, mas nao sei como inflar essa tela no arquivo AcompanhamentoFragment.java, pois não consigo acessar esses objetos, e se eu tento acessar esses elementos pelo MenuActivity.java ele acusa erro de NullPoint.

Comment: Se eu entendi qual é esse trecho de código, faltou você retornar o xml inflado `return acompanhamento;`

Comment: Mas eu preciso criar método para inflar um objeto? ou apenas instanciando o objeto View eu já consigo modificar os componentes da minha tela?

Comment: Ah, agora que vi que isso é uma `Activity`... Pra exibir o layout numa  `Activity` é melhor criar um [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments), que vai ter toda a lógica dessa "tela" e a interface (layout) também

Comment: Sim sim eu vi, o problema é que não consigo usar o findViewbyId, ele não permite quando é usado um fragmento, sem isso não consigo acessar os componentes do layout da minha tela. pois a activity faz extends de appCompatActivity, e um fragmento faz extends de fragment

Comment: No `Fragment` você precisa usar `findViewById` em alguma view. Em geral, seria na `view` que o `Fragment` está inflando: `view.findViewById`

Comment: eu editei a minha publicação, dentro do fragmento_acompanhamento.xml tenho um button e um textView igual na imagem anterior, como eu vou acessar eles pelo meu arquivo acompanhamentoFragmento.java?

Comment: Poste código ao invés de imagem, por favor. Fica mais fácil de eu (ou outra pessoa) responder

Comment: agora postei o código, resumindo, eu criei um menu do tipo Navigation Dreawer activity, e criei dois fragmentos que corresponde a dois itens do menu, visita e acompanhamento, no momento que eu clico em acompanhamento ele abre a tela fragment_acompanhamento.xml, até ai beleza, mas eu preciso acessar os compontentes dessa tela e alterar o texto de um textView com um clique, mas como eu acesso os componentes dessa tela? é por qual arquivo? o MenuActivity.java ou pelo Acompanhamento.java? e como eu faço isso? eu vejo varios exemplos de como inflar um xml mas nao funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Por qual arquivo acessar os elementos?**

Para acessar os componentes de um `layout.xml`, você deve acessar por quem [inflou](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) o `.xml`, que no seu caso está sendo o `AcompanhamentoFragment.java`.

**Como acessar os elementos?**

Para acessar um elemento partir de uma `Activity` é só usar o [`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)) (o elemento será procurado no Layout que você usou [`setContentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(android.view.View))), como você já faz na sua `Activity`:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    // Procurar pelo elemento no layout R.layout.activity_menu
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
}
```

No `Fragment` é bem similar, você precisa indicar em qual `View` você está querendo procurar por esse elemento. Segue exemplo:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acompanhamento, container, false);

    // Procurar pelo elemento no "view", que é o R.layout.fragment_acompanhamento
    Button meuBotao = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonteste);
    TextView meuTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewteste);

    return view;
}
```

A partir desse momento você já consegue realizar as alterações na interface que deseja, colocar um *listener* no botão etc.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado, agora deu certo!